# javascript verification of empty or null (is it correct?)

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm using javascript to do a verification if an input field is empty this way:

```
if($("#nu_username").val() == null || $("#nu_username").val() == ""){ 
    do action...
}
```

It works well, but I wonder if it's redundant to use both conditions. Do you know it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QjSYG/9/ May be helpful for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `null` and `""` are "falsy".

You can write

```
if (!$('#nu_username').val())
```

Comment: You are back! Mazal Tov! I haven't seen you around in a while ^_^.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks! It worked well and u helped me saving lots of characters!

Comment: @Neal: Thanks! I've been busy lately.

Comment: Be aware this will also fail for numeric `0`.

Comment: I don't think this will be a problem, @jbabey, because there's no field where the user should add a 0 value.

Comment: as a matter fact, @jbabey, I tried 0 and it wasnt considered false.

Comment: @Periback should work for you, then, just be aware if you ever need a field that accepts `0` :)

Comment: @Periback `!$('#nu_username').val()` is `true` for `0`, `$('#nu_username').val()` is `false` for `0`

Comment: @Periback: `0` is falsy, but `"0"` is truthy.  `.val()` on a textbox will never return `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Never compare with == or != when true/false is involved. Always use === and !==.

Asides from that, according to the [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/val/), val() is guaranteed to return null only if there are no matches for that selector; and will return "" (empty string) if a single field matches, but is empty.

Comment: Never compare with `==`, ever.

Comment: the only thing I want is to be sure that the user entered a value into the field, so what is the best way to do this? I followed @SLaks idea to replace the way I was doing and it worked well too.. should I change?